# Jenkins: Trigger build on commit from whitelist of users

Tags: git, jenkins, commit, whitelist

I'm trying to use the Jenkins git plugin to monitor a private git repo and trigger builds only on commits from specific whitelist of users. I see options for blacklisting specific user commits but not a whitelist. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I suppose the build process runs in the section `Execute shell`. If so, before its run, parse the commit and get its author via `git log -1 <commit> --pretty=%an`, `%cn` for its committer. And please have a look if the git plugin has provided any environment variable that points to the author or committer. If the name is in the whitelist, go on with the build. If not, exit at once to finish the jenkins job. The job will be always triggered, but the build does not run for all the commits.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thanks, i shall try this out